# Ubuntu server 20.04 temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: server, virtualbox, wget, static-ip, golang

I have installed ubuntu server 20.04 in VirtualBox and setup static ip address. now I am trying to install golang but shows this

```
"Resolving go.dev(godev)...failed:temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'go.dev'

wget go.dev/dl/go1.20.3. linux-amd64.tar.gz 

--2023-04-26 14:41:32-- http://go.dev/d1/go1.20.3.1inux-amd64.tar.gz Resolving go.dev (go.dev)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. wget: unable to resolve host address 'go.dev'


 wget https ://golang.org/di/go1.20.3. 1inux-amd64.tar.gz
 
--2023-04-26 14:50:32-- golang.org/dl/go1.20.3.1inux-amd64.tar.gz
 Resolving golang.org (golang.org)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. uget: unable to resolve host address 'golang.org'
```

Comment: I see what looks like an error message. I do not see a question or what commands you used to get this error. As written all anyone can say is it says temporary. Try again later.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu. I am doing a project which requires go lang. so I need to install go lang, but I get this error. I have set static IP and when I ping 8.8.8.8 it works as well.

Comment: Please do not use comments to add info for the question. Use edit and add the info to the question. Comments are where someone trying to help you asks for more info.

Comment: okay. noted. thank you

Comment: OK now that I can read it I can see what the error might be. I tried the line you have here. wget https ://golang.org/di/go1.20.3. 1inux-amd64.tar.gz The error is that you have the number 1inux not linux as I think it should be. That is the error I get.